# using ninject with layered asp.net mvc application and Entity Framework edmx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm working in asp.net mvc 4 with Entity Framework 5 (with edmx). I'm trying to get Ninject to work correctly, but using the bindings has got me quite confused. I've seen Ninject being used before, but that was in a WCF project where the DI was being set in the WCF-layer.

Right now I have 4 layers:

- DataAcces (contains edmx and repositories, which I will show later)
- BusinessLogic (standard BL)
- Common (models)
- Gui (a mvc4 project)

Now here's the tricky part: I want to use DI here. The way I saw it being used in my previous WCF-project was that my WCF-layer went to my DataAccess so I can use the kernel.bind.
Now I don't want that here. I'm not using WCF. I also don't want to call my DataAccess in my Gui.

Since I said I'd show some code for insight:

Repository in DataAccess

```
public class Repo: IRepo
    {
        Entities context = new Entities();

        public IQueryable<PictureSource> PictureSource
        {
            get { return context.PictureSource; }
        }
    }
```

my IRepository is just this:

```
public interface IRepository
    {
        IQueryable<PictureSource> PictureSource { get; }
    }
```

What I want to be able to do is in my BusinessLogic. I want to be able to do the following:

```
public List<Picture> GetStuff(IRepository Repo)
        {
          //code
        }
```

Now I've looked a lot on the internet. About 80% of the examples use Web Apim which is useless to me. The other 20% just seem to do whatever they want "because it's just a demo" and violate Gui-BL-DA principle. I've seen examples consisting of a single layer to examples doing Business Logic in Data Access.
The ninject wiki also didn't help me as I'm new to DI and I've only seen it being used in an existing application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to code using Poor-Man's-DI. Inject your dependencies in your constructor!

```
public class BusinessLogic
{ 
  private _repository;

  public BusinessLogic(IRepo repository) 
  { 
     _repository = repository;
  }

  public List<Picture> GetStuff()
  {
      _repository.PictureSource.Where(x=>x.Published == false);
  }
 }
```

Once you have your codebase right, register your dependencies in Ninject. Ninject then takes care to inject your Repository to you BusinessLogic class.

Please note that you have an IQueryable in your IRepo, which you should avoid (http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/03/IQueryable-api)

Edit:
This would be your solution structure and the references:

```
MVC4 (GUI)
 -> DataAccess
 -> BusinessLogic
 -> Common

You need to setup this references, to wire up your bindings.

BusinessLogic
 -> Common (including your Interfaces!)

DataAccess
 -> Common
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have to reference my Data Access in my Gui, which is bad (I've been told that consistently over the course of my few years).

Comment: Commonly you have a Bootstrapper. In there you register all your bindings. The Bootstrapper has references to your Data Access Layer. You GUI should depend on your IRepo, not on the Data Access Layer.

Comment: Yes, but my IRepository is also in my Data Access. I'm probably doing something wrong by doing that?

Comment: So you are talking about you project/dll layout? If you don't want to reference the Data Access, move you interfaces to a third project (e.g. Common) and reference this project from your GUI and your Data Access.

Comment: From my Gui, I go to my Business Logic so I can do Getall, GetById,... which is then gotten from my Data Access (edmx with Repositories). My Common layer only has the Models/ViewModels which are used in my Gui and Business Logic. I want to be able to use Dependency Injection without referencing my Data Access in my Gui. I have very limited experience with interfaces (school system here seems to neglect them) so I have no real idea what is possible with them. I don't know how moving the interfaces to the Common-layer could help me with that.

Comment: I've been told that it's bad practice to move these repositories from the Data Access. It can be that I've been told the wrong thing. I can presume with your solution that it's actually not a bad practice?

Comment: You should not use your DataAccess in your MVC controllers. Use the Interfaces for that. There has to be one place in your solution where your wire up your bindings and this place needs to know what to bind. So your have direct references to your DataAccess to wire things up, but dont't use your DataAccess directly.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm using the interfaces. My last question in the comments was whether or not I'm actually allowed to move my repositories out of my Data Access. I've always been told they have to stay inthere, which is the reason why I'm asking the current question.

Comment: Your repository implementation should stay in there, but you want to use your repository from outside, so access it through an interface.

Comment: Ah, It suddenly makes sence now. Where I'm now having my IRepository in my Data Access, I just have to move that to my common. I've always seen them as 2 parts of thesame thing, but now I get it. My inexperience with interfaces did this to me. Thank you for your answer, you helped clarify a lot to me now.

Comment: Glad it finally made sense to you :)

Comment: Just a quick question though: I'm trying to use my IRepository in my Common-layer now. The problem is now that I can't return an entity from EF via this route as it would result in a circular reference. Would it be allowed to use AutoMapper to map my Entity to a Model right in my Repository? Is there a better solution to this.
Right now I have 
Common -> IRepository
DataAcces -> Repository (references Common so that I can use Repository : IRepository)

Comment: Sure you can do that. This would make some things easier anyways. You can decouple your business logic from all the EF stuff. This paves the way to do Unit Tests of your Business Logic without having to rely on anything EF specific. BTW, please don't return IQueryable in your interface ;)

Comment: What I'm doing with the IQueryable is making is useable in my Business Logic to reduce database load. What I'm returning via my repositories is a table or view with ALL the data for ALL the situations/users that can be used for that screen. I understand that by making this Iqueryable, I can reduce database load as it will only generate a Sql statement when I finally take it off of being IQueryable. All I'm going to be using these interfaces for is GetById/Name, All,... and for Insert/Update, I'll be using stored procedures (still have to write all of those). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The problem with IQueryable is mainly, that you can't really mock it. So there is no chance to do a clean Unit Test. Please follow my link for more info.

Comment: I have read your article when you posted it and I've also read the comments. There is quite a bit of controversy around it. Also when I will be unit testing, I'll just be mocking my entire repository and not just the single IQueryable. No point in mocking something twice when it can be done in one time. But I've gotten myself stuck with the Repositories now, which requires a totally different question. I'll be making that now.

Answer (score 0):

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Load("*.dll");
```

This should load `NinjectModule`s in all `.dll`s in the current directory. So you don't need to add reference to the DAL.